# Background gradient problems

Tags: html, css, background, gradient

I try to make a gradient background for my Website. Can you please help me? I'm learning CSS/HTML right now. So the Background should have a gradient from red to yellow. I'm waiting for your answer c;

This is for my personal website

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, yellow);
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#card {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 75px;
  border-radius: 35px 35px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

#card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 25px 50px black;
}

#person {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c94370, #3a679a);
  font-size: 67px;
  font-size-adjust: 0.58;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', bold;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

#profile {
  display: block;
  height: 320px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 100% 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

#profile:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#mail {
  display: block;
  border: 5px solid #303030;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', bold;
  border-radius: 15px 15px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px 42px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #303030;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#mail:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #303030;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="oskar.png" type="image/png" />
  <link rel="icon" href="oskar.png" type="image/png" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="card">
    <img src="oskar.png" id="profile"> <br>
    <b id="person">Oskar </b><br><br>
    <button id="mail" onclick="window.location.href='mailto:mail@mail.mail?subject=Die%20Website%20ist%20krass'">E-Mail</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

i expect a gradient background in red and yellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS should look like this:

```
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, yellow);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: static;
}

#card {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 75px;
  border-radius: 35px 35px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

position: absolute is messing up the display of your background. This positions an element relative to it's parent. Since body's parent is the html tag, I'm not too certain where this positions the body, but it isn't where you're going to want it.

See here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

You also shouldn't be describing positioning inside of the body, as everything you put inside of it will try to be 50% away from the top and left. Same with transform. Those styles should be added to the actual element you're styling.

background-repeat: no-repeat, background-attachment: fixed, and position: static will make sure the gradient adjusts to the window size and doesn't bug out.

You can see how I added the height, width, and margin styles to your card class.

https://jsfiddle.net/AnthrOne/1guch73d/14/

Comment: Thx... thats it

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and how does your code solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) 
It seems to have what you're looking for. I think since the default is from top to bottom that the "to bottom" part in your code maybe causing the issue?

I tested it here at this [link](http://www.cssdesk.com/) and it appears to work either way (with or without the "to bottom").

Comment: So... i tried it with this code: https://hasteb.in/abunotey.css  Now it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/npyh41

Comment: I tried to make a picure for the background and its looks the same